# Problem with Pycharm using matlab engine: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matlab'

Tags: python, matlab, pycharm, matlab-engine

I'm trying to import matlab.engine in python. I've done it with Python shell and it works fine but when I do it in Pycharm it returns "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matlab'".

I've tried searching elsewhere on the internet but couldn't solve my problem.
I also saw a lot of forum questions redirecting to
[ImportError: No module named matlab.engine. How to import matlab.engine in Pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119675/importerror-no-module-named-matlab-engine-how-to-import-matlab-engine-in-pycha#new-answer?newreg=b79011e3d1de40ea83d04441e34b1360)

but I can't follow some of those steps like "go to File--> Settings --> Gear --> More --> Show all --> Show paths to the selected interpreter" maybe since my version of Pycharm is more recent and this has changed?

Also for the step:
"Then open cmd running as administrator and go to your root MATLAB installation directory and find such directory:

```
cd C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\engines\python\build\lib
```

Then type :

```
python setup.py install
```

."

I get the error: "Python is not found. Run without arguments to proceed"

Thanks for your help I'm completely lost. Also I'd like to state I've used Pycharm some years ago but it seems I'm quite rusted

Comment: Make sure PyCharm is using the same version of Python you use on the command line where things work correctly.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Yes it is the same version

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution that worked for me here is to go to "Python Packages" tab in Pycharm, type in "matlabengine" and simply install it. Really type matlabengine and not matlab.engine otherwise it doesn't find it